# Find entries with array of dates if any is currently available within a certain range in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, epoch

I have a postgres table with columns:

```
id: text
availabilities: integer[]
```

A certain ID can has multiply availabilities (different days (not continuous) in a range for up to a few years). Each availability is a Unix timestamp (in seconds) for a certain day.
Hours, minutes, seconds, ms are set to 0, i.e. a timestamp represents the start of a day.

**Question:**
How can I find all IDs very fast, which contain at least one availability inbetween a certain from-to range (also timestamp)?
I can also store them differently in an array, e.g "days since epoch", if needed (to get 1 (day) steps instead of 86400 (second) steps).

However, if possible (and speed is roughly same), I want to use an array and on row per each entry.

**Example:**

Data (0 = day-1, 86400 = day-2, ...)

```
| id |          availabilities            |

|  1 | [0 , 86400, 172800, 259200         ]
|  2 | [    86400,         259200         ]
|  3 | [                         , 345600 ]
|  4 | [         , 172800,                ]
|  5 | [0,                                ]
```

Now I want to get a list of IDs which contains at least 1 availability which:

- is between 86400 AND 259200 --> ID 1, 2, 4
- is between 172800 AND 172800 --> ID 1, 4
- is between 259200 AND (max-int) --> ID 1,2,3

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL `unnest` function is the best function for converting array elements to rows and gets the best performance. You can use this function. Sample Query:

```
with mytable as (
        select 1 as id, '{12,2500,6000,200}'::int[] as pint
        union all
        select 2 as id, '{0,200,3500,150}'::int[]
        union all
        select 4 as id, '{20,10,8500,1100,9000,25000}'::int[]
    )
select id, unnest(pint) as pt from mytable;

-- Return  
1   12
1   2500
1   6000
1   200
2   0
2   200
2   3500
2   150
4   20
4   10
4   8500
4   1100
4   9000
4   25000
```

Comment: So, you mean that I should convert it to rows and perform a sub-query on it to get my correct IDs?